# How can I pass the value of a variable in one method into another method?

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am attempting to create a code that sets three sides for a triangle, then calculates the perimeter of the triangle, the area of the triangle, and determines if the triangle is obtuse or not.  I have completed all of the code, and no errors are present.  When I run the program, nothing happens.  There is no output, and I cannot see what is happening in any of the methods I created.  If anyone can help me figure out where I went wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package triangle;

import java.lang.Math;
/**
 *
 * @author Dan
 */
public class Triangle 
{
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
    private double Area;
    private double Perim;

/**
 * Create Triangle object
 * @param sideA for side one
 * @param sideB for side two
 * @param sideC for side three
 */
    public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {

        if (sideA >= 0 || sideB >= 0 || sideC >= 0)
            System.exit(0);
        else
            side1 = sideA;
            side2 = sideB;
            side3 = sideC;
            System.out.println("The chosen values for each side are:");
            System.out.println("Side 1: " +side1);
            System.out.println("Side 2: " +side2);
            System.out.println("Side 3: " +side3);
            System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Create a method for calculating the perimeter
     * of a triangle
     */
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        Perim = side1+side2+side3;
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle is: " +Perim);
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Create a method for calculating the area
     * of a triangle
     */
    public void getArea()
    {
      Area =  Math.sqrt((Perim/2)*((Perim/2)-side1)*((Perim/2)-side2)*((Perim/2)-side3));
      System.out.println("The Area of the triangle is: " +Area );
      System.out.println();
    }
    /**Create a method to determine if a triangle is obtuse or not
     */
    public void isObtuse()
    {
        /**
         * determines if the square of two sides is less than the square of the remaining side
         */
        if ((Math.pow(side1,2) + Math.pow(side2,2) < Math.pow(side3,2)) ||
            (Math.pow(side3,2) + Math.pow(side1,2) < Math.pow(side2,2)) ||
            (Math.pow(side3,2) + Math.pow(side2,2) < Math.pow(side1,2)))
            System.out.println("The triangle is obtuse: 1");
        else
            System.out.println("The triangle is not obtuse: 0");

    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Triangle tri = new Triangle(10,20,30);
        System.out.println(tri.Perim);
        System.out.println(tri.Area);
        tri.isObtuse();

    }

}
```

Comment: What aren't you using the methods for perimeter and area that you created?

Comment: @TheDude I expect he/she is accustomed to C# properties.

Comment: how come there is no compilation error, `double getPerimeter()` doesn't return any thing.

Comment: your method names are not in sync with their behaviors. `isObtuse` and `getArea`return void, where as their names suggest to return boolean and a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

When the `Triangle` instance is created, the *constructor* is called. The following code in your constructor:

```
if (sideA >= 0 || sideB >= 0 || sideC >= 0) {
    System.exit(0); // exit program
}
```

will *finish* the program when any of the sides of the triangles is `>= 0`.

The `||` operator is the logical `OR`, which means that if any of the conditions is `true`, the *whole expression* will be `true`.

So, if the triangle sides are `10`, `20` and `30`. Since they are positive (`>=0`) values, the program will finish when the condition is reached.

**Also**, you should add a `return` statement in the method `getPerimeter`, because its return type is `double`, not `void`:

```
return Perim;
```

Comment: 5 second debug would be enough to find this out easily.

Comment: It's also only part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These lines don't make any sense:

```
if (sideA >= 0 || sideB >= 0 || sideC >= 0)
        System.exit(0);
```

This says "if sideA, sideB, or sideC is greater than 0 then exit the program." Which doesn't work for the three values you passed to the constructor (10,20,30). Perhaps you wanted to check if less than or equal to zero (`<= 0`)?

After that you need to call your `getPerimeter()` and `getArea()` methods in order to have values in the `Area` and `Perim` fields of your class. Your `getPerimeter()` method doesn't have to return anything so the `double` in the method declaration is unnecessary, because you don't return anything. It can be just `public void getPerimeter()`.

Side Note: Standardly the names of fields start with a lower case letter and use camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, some variables must be initialized with some way. For example, what I do usually is this:

```
//...
private double side1;
private double side2;
private double side3;
private double Area;
private double Perim;

public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC){
    Area = 0.0;
    Perim = 0.0;
//...
}
```

It's more appropriate, since you use those variables to your methods below.
Now, your statement `if (sideA >= 0 || sideB >= 0 || sideC >= 0) System.exit(0);` actually sais "if at least one of sides sides is positive number, exit the program." I would suggest that you should change it to

```
if (sideA <= 0 || sideB <= 0 || sideC <= 0) System.exit(0);
else
//...
```

change those little things and let me know.